# Flutter Camera - Cannot capture image due to "unconfigured surface"

Tags: android, flutter, camera, android-camera, android-camera2

Can somebody tell me what I have done wrong... I wanted to capture the image and display a preview screen showing the captured image. It worked fine before, but once I added object detection, I receive a group of errors every time I try to take a photo. I think the object detection is interfering with the capturing.

```
I/flutter (12681): /data/user/0/com.example.iSPY_Cancer/cache/2020-07-26 14:11:55.456052.png
E/CameraDevice-0-LE(12681): submitRequestList - cannot use a surface that wasn't configured
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera(12681): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera(12681): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad argument passed to camera service
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera(12681):   at android.hardware.camera2.utils.CameraBinderDecorator.throwOnError(CameraBinderDecorator.java:114)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera(12681):   at android.hardware.camera2.utils.CameraBinderDecorator$CameraBinderDecoratorListener.onAfterInvocation(CameraBinderDecorator.java:73)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera(12681):   at android.hardware.camera2.utils.Decorator.invoke(Decorator.java:81)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera(12681):   at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:393)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera(12681):   at $Proxy1.submitRequestList(Unknown Source)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera(12681):   at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.submitCaptureRequest(CameraDeviceImpl.java:853)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera(12681):   at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.capture(CameraDeviceImpl.java:741)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera(12681):   at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.capture(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:179)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera(12681):   at io.flutter.plugins.camera.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:253)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera(12681):   at io.flutter.plugins.camera.MethodCallHandlerImpl.onMethodCall(MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:77)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera(12681):   at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:226)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera(12681):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera(12681):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:631)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera(12681):   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera(12681):   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera(12681):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:141)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera(12681):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5603)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera(12681):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera(12681):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera(12681):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
I/flutter (12681): CameraException(error, Bad argument passed to camera service)
```

Here is the code for image capturing. As seen in the first line of the errors, the image `path` is successfully printed, which means the code leading up to `print(path)` is successful, but the rest doesn't work. If anyone has encountered these errors before, please help me. I am really stuck.

```
void _onCapturePressed(context) async {
    // Take the Picture in a try / catch block. If anything goes wrong,

    // catch the error.

    try {
      // Attempt to take a picture and log where it's been saved

      final path = join(
        // In this example, store the picture in the temp directory. Find

        // the temp directory using the `path_provider` plugin.

        (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path,

        '${DateTime.now()}.png',
      );

      print(path);

      await controller.takePicture(path);

      // If the picture was taken, display it on a new screen

      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => PreviewImageScreen(imagePath: path),
        ),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      // If an error occurs, log the error to the console.

      print(e);
    }
  }
```

And this is the code for the entire screen with object detection:

```
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:tflite/tflite.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

import '../preview_screen.dart';
import 'models.dart';

typedef void Callback(List<dynamic> list, int h, int w);

class Camera extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<CameraDescription> cameras;  
  final Callback setRecognitions;
  final String model;

  Camera(this.cameras, this.model, this.setRecognitions);

  @override
  _CameraState createState() => new _CameraState();
}

class _CameraState extends State<Camera> {
  double xPosition = 120;
  double yPosition = 150;

  List cameras;
  int selectedCameraIdx;
  String imagePath;

  CameraController controller;
  bool isDetecting = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    if (widget.cameras == null || widget.cameras.length < 1) {
      print(widget.cameras);
      print('No camera is found');
    } else {
      controller = new CameraController(
        widget.cameras[0],
        ResolutionPreset.high,
      );
      controller.initialize().then((_) {
        if (!mounted) {
          return;
        }
        setState(() {});

        controller.startImageStream((CameraImage img) {
          if (!isDetecting) {
            isDetecting = true;

            int startTime = new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;

            if (widget.model == mobilenet) {
              Tflite.runModelOnFrame(
                bytesList: img.planes.map((plane) {
                  return plane.bytes;
                }).toList(),
                imageHeight: img.height,
                imageWidth: img.width,
                numResults: 2,
              ).then((recognitions) {
                int endTime = new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
                print("Detection took ${endTime - startTime}");

                widget.setRecognitions(recognitions, img.height, img.width);

                isDetecting = false;
              });
            } else if (widget.model == posenet) {
              Tflite.runPoseNetOnFrame(
                bytesList: img.planes.map((plane) {
                  return plane.bytes;
                }).toList(),
                imageHeight: img.height,
                imageWidth: img.width,
                numResults: 2,
              ).then((recognitions) {
                int endTime = new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
                print("Detection took ${endTime - startTime}");

                widget.setRecognitions(recognitions, img.height, img.width);

                isDetecting = false;
              });
            } else {
              Tflite.detectObjectOnFrame(
                bytesList: img.planes.map((plane) {
                  return plane.bytes;
                }).toList(),
                model: widget.model == yolo ? "YOLO" : "SSDMobileNet",
                imageHeight: img.height,
                imageWidth: img.width,
                imageMean: widget.model == yolo ? 0 : 127.5,
                imageStd: widget.model == yolo ? 255.0 : 127.5,
                numResultsPerClass: 1,
                threshold: widget.model == yolo ? 0.2 : 0.4,
              ).then((recognitions) {
                int endTime = new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
                print("Detection took ${endTime - startTime}");

                widget.setRecognitions(recognitions, img.height, img.width);

                isDetecting = false;
              });
            }
          }
        });
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (controller == null || !controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return Container();
    }

    var tmp = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    var screenH = math.max(tmp.height, tmp.width);
    var screenW = math.min(tmp.height, tmp.width);
    tmp = controller.value.previewSize;
    var previewH = math.max(tmp.height, tmp.width);
    var previewW = math.min(tmp.height, tmp.width);
    var screenRatio = screenH / screenW;
    var previewRatio = previewH / previewW;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
          centerTitle: true,
          elevation: 5,
          title: Text("Pathomatic")),
      body: Container(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: new Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: _cameraPreviewWidget(context),
                    ),
                    new Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: GestureDetector(
                          child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                            Positioned(
                              top: yPosition,
                              left: xPosition,
                              child: Container(
                                // padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 200.0, left: 20.0),
                                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3,
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3,
                                child:
                                    Image.asset('assets/images/crosshair.png'),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ]),
                          onPanUpdate: (tapInfo) {
                            setState(() {
                              xPosition += tapInfo.delta.dx;
                              yPosition += tapInfo.delta.dy;
                            });
                          }),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10.0,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  _cameraTogglesRowWidget(),
                  _captureControlRowWidget(context),
                  Spacer()
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10.0)
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _cameraPreviewWidget(context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    if (!controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return Container();
    }

    return ClipRect(
      child: Container(
        child: Transform.scale(
          scale: controller.value.aspectRatio / size.aspectRatio,
          child: Center(
            child: AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
              child: CameraPreview(controller),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  /// Display the control bar with buttons to take pictures

  Widget _captureControlRowWidget(context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: [
            FloatingActionButton(
                child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
                backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
                onPressed: () {
                  _onCapturePressed(context);
                })
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  /// Display a row of toggle to select the camera (or a message if no camera is available).

  Widget _cameraTogglesRowWidget() {
    if (cameras == null || cameras.isEmpty) {
      return Spacer();
    }

    CameraDescription selectedCamera = cameras[selectedCameraIdx];

    CameraLensDirection lensDirection = selectedCamera.lensDirection;

    ///         CHNAGE THIS TO INCREASE MAGNIFICATION
    ///
    return Expanded(
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: FlatButton.icon(
            onPressed: _onSwitchCamera,
            icon: Icon(_getCameraLensIcon(lensDirection), color: Colors.white),
            label: Text(
              "10x",
              // "${lensDirection.toString().toUpperCase().substring(lensDirection.toString().indexOf('.') + 1)}",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            )),
      ),
    );
  }

  IconData _getCameraLensIcon(CameraLensDirection direction) {
    switch (direction) {
      case CameraLensDirection.back:
        return Icons.camera_rear;

      case CameraLensDirection.front:
        return Icons.camera_front;

      case CameraLensDirection.external:
        return Icons.camera;

      default:
        return Icons.device_unknown;
    }
  }

  void _onSwitchCamera() {
    selectedCameraIdx =
        selectedCameraIdx < cameras.length - 1 ? selectedCameraIdx + 1 : 0;

    CameraDescription selectedCamera = cameras[selectedCameraIdx];

    // _initCameraController(selectedCamera);
  }

  void _onCapturePressed(context) async {
    // Take the Picture in a try / catch block. If anything goes wrong,

    // catch the error.

    try {
      // Attempt to take a picture and log where it's been saved

      final path = join(
        // In this example, store the picture in the temp directory. Find

        // the temp directory using the `path_provider` plugin.

        (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path,

        '${DateTime.now()}.png',
      );

      print(path);

      await controller.takePicture(path);

      // If the picture was taken, display it on a new screen

      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => PreviewImageScreen(imagePath: path),
        ),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      // If an error occurs, log the error to the console.

      print(e);
    }
  }



  // CAMERA EXCEPTION METHOD
  
  // void _showCameraException(CameraException e) {
  //   String errorText = 'Error: ${e.code}\nError Message: ${e.description}';

  //   print(errorText);

  //   print('Error: ${e.code}\n${e.description}');
  // }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stopping the image stream before take the picture? I have a feeling something sus is happening there.